# Creating Say Command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating "say" command for my bot and it is fine, But when I tag someone in-between content it does not send the remaining message.

For Example:

> !say [user mention] take your role
> asap

but the output is:

> [user mention]

Code:

```
@bot.command(name='say')
async def audit(ctx, msg=None):
    if msg is not None:
        await ctx.send(msg)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you seperate arguments by spaces. To make argument that has space inside it simply put `*` inside of the `async def audit(ctx, msg=None):` like that:

```py
async def audit(ctx, *, msg=None):
```

then discordpy will know that everything after `!say` should be an argument.